# Can a cracked antivrus software do the job?

Tags: authentication, antivirus, software, password-cracking

Some of my friends say that their cracked antivirus software updates regularly, and does the job as same as a legitimate software would do. Is this possible? How do they bypass the activation key checker, and do that?

Comment: Why on earth would you even want to do this, when there are plenty of perfectly decent free anti-virus options available?

Comment: it doesn't answer my question. What I wanted to know is, how it works.

Comment: That's why I added it as a comment, and not an answer.  ;-)

Comment: That's like asking if a used needle can deliver a vaccine. I guess the short answer is yes, long answer is your computer risks getting hepatitis.

Comment: yes and I never mentioned that I want to use a cracked software

Comment: Insufficient information to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: I think that the downvotes are a bit unnecessary; OP was ignorant, and the answer corrected that. This could be useful to others

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bypassing the activation key checker on any software usually isn't a problem. It's a relatively simple task of reverse engineering the binary and making the necessary modifications.

Can a cracked antivirus perform it's job? Yes, most definitely. The **problem** is that you have no idea what other modifications have been made to the binary in the process of bypassing the DRM. A rootkit or other sorts of malware could have been packaged with the antivirus binary for all you know.

Comment: Local jerk here used a similar scam as a means of passing around RAT software. Brought to you by your local chapter of "Trust-a-Crook". If they'll steal from others, they'll steal from you.

Comment: A cracked anti-virus should be unable to download new versions/definitions from the official severs.